# application with argument in the console

Tags: c#, arguments

I have an application which takes several arguments entered in the console :
here is an example :

```
MyApp.exe -D 23/01/2014 -B True
```

according to these arguments the application will behave differently
how can I add that in my code

Comment: I am not following. Do you mean how do you get at these arguments from within your code?

Comment: Well, you receive them as a string array in your `Main` method, and then you just handle them... you can either do that manually or use a library such a https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline

Comment: how can I do it manually ? this is the real question , I'm a beginner on c# dev

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx) about how you can acecss theres arguments.

Comment: In the example I wrote : I have an option with the argument

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean, that some of the arguments are optional? In that case you can count the number of arguments and call a method accordingly.
Maybe you can post a code example of what you got so far and explain a little more about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: for example :
Myapp.exe -D 01/01/2014 -F "filepath" -B "true"
the user can put arguments in any order he want or he can put just one or two arguments (so the option will help me to differentiate between arguments)

Comment: It seems like you always have a flag or an identifier followed by the value. So you could check args[1], args[3], etc. for the flag (-D, -B, etc.) and evaluate args[2], args[4].. accordingly. However you will have to manually make sure that the flag-parameter-pair makes sense and throw errors when something like Myapp.exe -D "filepath" occurs.

Answer (score 0):

just want to add to boldty answer, if you are using VS you can add those args so each time you debug you will get them, right click project -> properties -> debug -> and in start options there is a text area called command line args, hope this helps.